# Emulator app throws unexpected null value

Tags: flutter

I have a program run on emulator of flutter application. It throws the error "unexpected null value" even though it doesn't making errors in analyzer. It is fibonacci series i don't know why making error in emulator. I write this code according to null safety.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
void main() async {
  final numbers = FibonacciNumbers();

  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Fibonacci List'),
        ),
        body: FibonacciListView(numbers),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class FibonacciNumbers {
  final cache = {0: BigInt.from(1), 1: BigInt.from(1)};
  BigInt get(int i) {
    if (!cache.containsKey(i)) {
      cache[i] = get(i - 1) + get(i - 2);
    }
    return cache['$i']!;
  }
}

class FibonacciListView extends StatelessWidget {
  //static const route ='/pagetwo';
  FibonacciNumbers? numbers;
  FibonacciListView(this.numbers);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Navigator.pushNamed(context,FibonacciListView.route);
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          title: Text('Fibonacci List'),
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: numbers!.cache.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, i) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text('${numbers!.get(i)}'),
              onTap: () {
                final snack = SnackBar(
                  content: Text('${numbers!.get(i)} is '
                      '#$i in the Fibonacci sequence!'),
                );
                Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snack);
              },
            );
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Please copy-paste the exact error message you get into your question! And tell us where exactly in your code the error happens.

Comment: And plz accept my edit! It makes your qn so much clearer and easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Your error comes from this line:

```dart
return cache['$i']!;
```

You declared `cache` as a `Map` of `<int, BigInt>`. To access the value, you should return:

```dart
return cache[i]!;
```

I also replaced the display of snackbar, since `showSnackBar` is deprecated for class `Scaffold`.

Here is the updated code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  final numbers = FibonacciNumbers();

  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Fibonacci List'),
        ),
        body: FibonacciListView(numbers),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class FibonacciNumbers {
  final cache = {0: BigInt.from(1), 1: BigInt.from(1)};
  
  BigInt get(int i) {
    if (!cache.containsKey(i)) {
      cache[i] = get(i - 1) + get(i - 2);
    }

    return cache[i]!;
  }
}

class FibonacciListView extends StatelessWidget {
  final FibonacciNumbers numbers;
  const FibonacciListView(this.numbers, {super.key});
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        title: Text('Fibonacci List'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: numbers.cache.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text('${numbers.get(i).toString()}'),
            onTap: () {
              final snack = SnackBar(
                content: Text('${numbers.get(i)} is #$i in the Fibonacci sequence!'),
              );
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snack);
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Oooooooh, nice catch!  abdelrahmandarrage, Lucie is right, that's a string of an int, not an actual int. But what about the `final` keyword that I mentioned in my answer, @Lucie? I see you've kept it... But isn't that a problem when you want to add elements?

Comment: final means you can't reassign `cache` with a new Map. But the Map is not immutable, you can add or remove entries from it

Comment: So basically, it's the pointer to the map that's immutable... I.e. its address. But not its content. Yes?

Answer (score 0):

This seems problematic, to me:

```
itemCount: numbers!.cache.length,
```

If you wanted the item count to update when the length of cache changes, it won't. You will get only those two first items that correspond to the original length of cache.

If you want an infinite ListView of fibonacci numbers, however, you can just remove the `itemCount` property from the `ListView.builder()` altogether! This will make the builder generate as many List elements as it can fit on the screen, plus a few more to be prepared for when the user scrolls. Then, as they scroll, more elements will be generated eternally.

That seems like a nice solution, if that's what you wanted!  Otherwise, I agree with Lucie's excellent answer.